# IP forwarding, masquareding, NAT

Tags: linux, networking, ip, bridge, nat

I have one physical interface `eth0` on my target, running Linux.
The IP address of this interface is 172.16.81.*x* (public IP).

I have to create a virtual interface `eth0:1` with IP address 173.1.1.*x*.
I will be running socket server with custom port 49155 using IP address 173.1.1.*x*.

From another PC/target I should not be able to ping 173.1.1.*x*.
However, from another PC I will be running a socket client program.
This client should be able to connect to port 49155 on the 172.16.81.*x* public IP.

I have tried NAT, bridge but not successful.

with below iptable rules, was able to establish server<-->client communication:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o 173.1.1.6 -p tcp --syn --dport 49155 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o 173.1.1.6 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o 173.1.1.6 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 49155 -j DNAT --to-destination 173.1.1.6
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens33 -p tcp --dport 49155 -d 173.1.1.6 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.233.251
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -s 192.168.233.251 --dport 49155 -j ACCEPT
```

at this point still 173.1.1.6 is pingable from outside PC.

however i have to also make 173.1.1.6 invisible for external world for that i add below rules:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 173.1.1.6 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s 173.1.1.6 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 173.1.1.6 -j DROP
```

after this ping is blocked. server <--> client communication also doesnt happen.

Comment: Why are you setting up the address 173.1.1.x if nobody is supposet to connect to it? Is there some other requirement that you haven't described but need to satisfy? Also, 172.16.81.x is not a true globally unique public IP: it is part of the 172.16.0.0/12 (i.e. from 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255) range of addresses reserved for private networks, and cannot be succesfully connected to the worldwide internet without a NAT device in between. However, 173.1.1.x could be a true public IP address.

Comment: when i meant public, i meant within our private network.

Comment: once this basic setup is working, i would be extending this by creating vlan interfaces and assigning 173.1.1.x ip address to those vlan interfaces

Comment: Your question seems to be a total mess. What does the IP aliasing have to do with all the forward/masquerade stuff? Also your assumption is simply wrong. By default Linux will respond to ARP regardless of whether the requested IP is assigned on the interface that the ARP came through. Even if you change that with the `arp_ignore` sysctl, it does not mean it will respond to IP traffics only if the destination IP address matches one that is assigned on the interface.

Comment: If you are actually going to do something that can be achieved with VLAN, then just start with VLAN. There's nothing for you to extend from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have no idea what you are actually trying to set up or achieve ultimately, given the the following case:

1. You have two IP addresses configured on the same host (regardless of whether they are configured on the same network interface)
2. You have some server program that binds to one of the addresses
3. You do not want other hosts to be able to reach this host with the address bound by the aforementioned program (regardless of whether they are trying to connect to the program / port).
4. You want other hosts to be able to connect to the aforementioned program with the other address that it is not bound to.

Regardless of whether the above makes any sense in any scenario, you can do it with the following iptables rules:

(Say it has the IP addresses of `192.168.1.2` and `192.168.2.2`, and the server program binds to `192.168.2.2:80`, and I want the other hosts to be able to connect to it with `192.168.1.2:8080`)

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.2.2 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.2:80
```

(Note: these rules are applied on the host itself, not its gateway or so; since you included `FORWARD` rules that I can't make sense out of, I have no idea what or where you were doing)

The key here is to use `raw (PREROUTING)` instead of `filter (INPUT)` to drop the unwanted traffics, as `filter (INPUT)` is matched against after `nat (PREROUTING)` is.

You probably do NOT want to add an inbound interface match (`-i`) to the first rule, since you apparently want the address to be completely "invisible". (Well, maybe you want something like `! -i`...again, I have no idea what you actually want to do, so.) For the second one, it depends on in what cases you want the DNAT to occur.

For the record, I don't see any reason for you to use a public IP for this purpose anyway (although to be fair, even if you use a private IP, you'll need to choose one that does not conflict with private subnets that this host would need to reach).

P.S. As far as I know, what you called "virtual interface" is nothing but an archaic way to configure more than one IP address on one network interface.

Comment: thanks Tom Yan for the reply and your patience. yes using "raw (PREROUTING)" helped the objective. sorry about using have used "public ip" term. i meant to convey an IP accessible in our LAN. the final objective for me is to have multiple vlan's on which our socket programs will run. all these vlan's are to be working on top of a single NIC and a single ip address.

Comment: I was not referring to `172.16.81.x (public IP)` though. Rather as someone mentioned above, `173.1.1.x` *is* a public IP. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network